# How to run C program from Python using Popen and pipes, so that e.g. scanf() waits for input on the pipe?

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

> How to run C program from Python using Popen and pipes, so that e.g. scanf() waits for input on the pipe?

I want to create a C-program subprocess and run it interactively using pipes:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['./echo'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.stdin.write('Bob')
```

The C-program:

```
puts("Enter your name:");
scanf("%s", &input);
printf(input)
```

Now, the problem is that `scanf()` doesn't wait for my input, but instead returns immediately. This happens both using `shell=True` and without.

How can I make the pipes behave appropriately to make e.g. `scanf()` wait for user input?